# Creating and updating a static HTML page with React.js or Next.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm building an app where registered users can create a list of items that they're selling where visitors (unregistered users) can access and only view the said list.

As visitors would mainly be using mobile devices, for faster load times I want a way to create a static webpage that would only display the list loaded from a database and the static webpage SHOULD UPDATE when the database is updated. Unfortunately, I have no control over the frequency of registered user updates (most people would probably build a list and leave it alone for a long while).

As I understand, Next.js does static generation on build time but I cannot build the application everytime someone updates their data. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked into [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration)? It allows you to update existing pages by re-rendering them in the background as traffic comes in.

Comment: The revalidate option definitely helps a ton. Thank you.